# How can I stop Visual Studio from overwriting my Xamarin Android project file on build?

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, msbuild, csproj

I am making an app with multiple build configurations for different clients and I am trying to keep a different Resources folder for each client so they have their own colours, logos, etc. Here is part of my MyProject.Android.csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    ...
    <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Base\Resource.designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
    <AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
    <MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>Resources\Base</MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' Or '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <AndroidAsset Include="Assets\Base\PrivacyPolicy.html" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\Base\mipmap-anydpi-v26\icon.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\Base\mipmap-anydpi-v26\icon_round.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\Base\drawable\logo.png">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateGeneratedFiles</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
    etc...
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'ClientTwoDebug|AnyCPU' ">
    ...
    <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\ClientTwo\Resource.designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
    <AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
    <MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>Resources\ClientTwo</MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'ClientTwoDebug' Or '$(Configuration)' == 'ClientTwoRelease'">
    <AndroidAsset Include="Assets\ClientTwo\PrivacyPolicy.html" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\ClientTwo\mipmap-anydpi-v26\icon.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\ClientTwo\mipmap-anydpi-v26\icon_round.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\ClientTwo\drawable\logo.png">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateGeneratedFiles</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
    etc...
</ItemGroup>
```

When I build my project in the default debug (base) configuration it will take some values and drawables and put them into their own item group with no condition along with the Resources file path being put in the default property group. See below:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\ClientTwo\values\styles.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\Base\values\colors.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\ClientTwo\drawable\logo.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\ClientTwo\values\Strings.xml" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\ClientTwo\values\colors.xml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateGeneratedFiles</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
    ...
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
    <AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
    <MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>Resources</MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I want to keep them separate as they include different colours and logos but Visual Studio will not let me. What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve this?

Comment: `but Visual Studio will not let me` Did you get any errors or prompts?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Not that I know of. I finally got it working using a combination of clean/build, deleting bin/obj folders, and excluding files (such as colors.xml) from different builds before running so it was forced to use the correct one, then include them after it ran correctly. The problem still occurs but I can manage it easier now.